# When to use Tabu Search or Genetic Algorithms and when not?

Tags: metaheuristics, local-search, genetic-algorithm

Are there any rules of thumb about when to implement which? For example, I am trying to solve OR scheduling problems. I see that majority of people have implemented Genetic Algorithms. However, more recently, several people have implemented Tabu Search Algorithms. I want to know if there is any guideline?

Comment: Related question: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7588/optimization-solution-framework/7591